# While Loops in Ruby Pt.2

Tags: ruby

I want the program to exit only after I say `'BYE'` 3 times *consecutively*. My program as of now, exits when I say `'BYE'` 3 times, but I don't know how to make it consecutive. I am at a complete loss.

```
what_said = 'Hi!'
bye_count = 0

while (bye_count < 3)
  what_said = gets.chomp
  if (what_said == 'BYE')
    if (bye_count < 2)
    bye_count += 1
    puts 'WHAT DID YOU SAY??'
    else
      bye_count += 1
      puts 'FINE! LEAVE YOUR POOR GRANDMA TO DIE.'
    end
  else
    if (what_said == what_said.upcase)
      puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + rand(1930...1951).to_s + '!'
    else
      puts 'HUH!? SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ha... I have a solution to that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is that if you get something other than bye - reset the counter to 0 again

```
what_said = 'Hi!'
bye_count = 0

while (bye_count < 3)
  what_said = gets.chomp
  if (what_said == 'BYE')
    if (bye_count < 2)
      bye_count += 1
      puts 'WHAT DID YOU SAY??'
    else
      bye_count += 1
      puts 'FINE! LEAVE YOUR POOR GRANDMA TO DIE.'
    end
  else
    # didn't get bye, so reset counter to 0 again
    bye_count = 0

    if (what_said == what_said.upcase)
      puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + rand(1930...1951).to_s + '!'
    else
      puts 'HUH!? SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I know just writing thank you's in the comments is kind of frowned upon. But thank you so much. I literally laughed at how easy it was once I saw what I had to do. This is genius stuff.

Comment: :D glad to be of service :D

Comment: Thanks, haha. I've got another question up.